# Getting issue while uploading a heavy CSV or Excel file of rows more than 750k like large data set

Tags: php, excel, csv, import

I have heavy excel files to import to my MySQL Database after bit processing in PHP.
So I tried multiple php libraries for Excel and CSV reading large data set.

But facing a common issue among all them, that after processing upto 170k records are read (randomly on each run like 130k or 150k or 160k).

I am in a worst situation where I am unable to identify what is the exact issue, which is stopping the further reading of files.

I don't think there is memory issue, or any other CPU issue.

Tried setting the

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '3G');
```

and also tried this:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Also tried converting xlsx files to csv and then importing, then only I am able to get 150k around records processed. From xlsx files only few thousand records are getting processed. The CSV File size is 220MB.

And I have tried uploading to my Laptop (8GB RAM with latest Windows 10 and all latest hardware), and on AWS (T2 Small/Mini) Server as well. On AWS only I am getting the above mentioned numbers, while on Laptop is gets stopped in few thousand records only.

Please suggest whether some other approach needs to be followed.

The code I wrote is:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
include __DIR__.'/../config.php';

require(DIR_LIB_PATH.'spreadsheet-reader/reader_writer/php-excel-reader/excel_reader2.php');
require(DIR_LIB_PATH.'spreadsheet-reader/reader_writer/SpreadsheetReader.php');

$file_path = '/path/to/file.csv';
$reader = new SpreadsheetReader($file_path);
foreach($reader as $row_data)
{
    $inserted_row = insertLead($row_data);
}
```

Comment: You may be better off loading the file into a temporary table ( Use LOAD DATA - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) and then processing this table (could use INSERT... SELECT if the processing is simple enough)

Comment: Which is the PHP fatal displayed? Or some other error

Comment: I don't know where I can see the error, as i am running it on server with nohup php command. so the output file isn't giving anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use spout http://opensource.box.com/spout/ with php to read very large excel files without any issue. It is a very excellent and fast php library to read write large excel files. And also try using batch insert otherwise it will be very slow inserting each row one by one.

Comment: I tried spout and it doesn't process after 27k on local computer and 160k around on AWS Mini Server. Didn't try the batch insert, will do so

Comment: I used spout in Laravel. It took around 4 minutes to batch update 4 lac records in mysql database while reading from an excel file. Batch insert is even much faster than batch update. I suggest batch insert in chunks of a few thousands records at a time, then unset the data array and add next batch of records and so on.