# xls parser for laravel for very large files

Tags: php, excel, laravel, parsing, xls

Is there any package for laravel (also for lumen) that could help me parse(read) huge xls files ? I mention huge because packages like maatwebsite/excel, phpoffice/phpspreadsheet do not help. I need for xls not for xlsx. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

phpoffice's phpspreadsheet does in fact have support for `.xls` files, as can be found in the [reading column](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) of the table on their documentation page.

**edit 1:**

The mentioned package has support for reading in chunks:

```
This can be particularly useful for conserving memory, by allowing you to read and process a large workbook in "chunks": an example of this usage might be when transferring data from an Excel worksheet to a database.
```

---

```
$inputFileType = 'Xls';
$inputFileName = './sampleData/example2.xls';

/**  Define a Read Filter class implementing \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter  */
class ChunkReadFilter implements \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\IReadFilter
{
    private $startRow = 0;
    private $endRow   = 0;

    /**  Set the list of rows that we want to read  */
    public function setRows($startRow, $chunkSize) {
        $this->startRow = $startRow;
        $this->endRow   = $startRow + $chunkSize;
    }

    public function readCell($column, $row, $worksheetName = '') {
        //  Only read the heading row, and the configured rows
        if (($row == 1) || ($row >= $this->startRow && $row < $this->endRow)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

/**  Create a new Reader of the type defined in $inputFileType  **/
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

/**  Define how many rows we want to read for each "chunk"  **/
$chunkSize = 2048;
/**  Create a new Instance of our Read Filter  **/
$chunkFilter = new ChunkReadFilter();

/**  Tell the Reader that we want to use the Read Filter  **/
$reader->setReadFilter($chunkFilter);

/**  Loop to read our worksheet in "chunk size" blocks  **/
for ($startRow = 2; $startRow <= 65536; $startRow += $chunkSize) {
    /**  Tell the Read Filter which rows we want this iteration  **/
    $chunkFilter->setRows($startRow,$chunkSize);
    /**  Load only the rows that match our filter  **/
    $spreadsheet = $reader->load($inputFileName);
    //    Do some processing here
}
```

---

```
See samples/Reader/12_Reading_a_workbook_in_chunks_using_a_configurable_read_filter_ for a working example of this code.
```

Comment: Yes, but I said that I am going to use huge files(more than 600.000 lines). So for huge files it has memory problems and if I  use chunk is extremely slow

Comment: Thanks, I have tested the code. It parses xls files but is extremely slow. I have tested on a file that has over 600.000 lines and it has passed 11 minutes and yet not finished parsing :)
I would need something that parses in aprox 1 minute

Comment: @Michelle hmm, your options are limited then, but i did manage to find this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48788088/6056864

Comment: Quezler thanks a lot for all your efforts. I use box/spout package and it works very well, it's fast and memory efficient but unfortunatelly it does not have support for xls. It only works for xlsx,csv,ods.